# What are the differences between renderman and cycles? How can I learn renderman?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders, renderman-render-engine

I'm quite a newbie with Blender, learned little about a modeling and shading. I was wondering on the Internet the other day and I saw that Pixar's Renderman is available for Blender.

What are the differences between Renderman's rendering engine and Cycles?
(I'm talking about Renderman 21).

My next question is, what resources are available to learn shading and lighting for Renderman INSIDE blender?

I'm also looking for tutorials explaining Renderman 21's shaders.

I saw this thing about Pixar's new Surface Shader that was used for Finding Dory and other PIXAR movies.

If you have any extra information about Pixar's Renderman 21, please do not hesitate. I'm trying to learn the most recent and advanced workflow for shading and lighting and it seems to be like Renderman 21 is what I am looking far.

Whether they are free or paid courses, I don't mind. Just direct to the right path.

Comment: Please show what internet research you have done and place that in your question.  Showing your current work is useful.  You may be getting near the point of having too many [subjective] questions in your BSE question here.

Comment: I've read all about it in Pixar's website. Here: https://renderman.pixar.com/view/p-renderman. 
I also read everything here:       https://renderman.pixar.com/view/renderman4blender 
 I read few articles comparing Cycles and Renderman and seems like the later does better.  I'm asking those who are experienced with Renderman 21 INSIDE blender. I wanna learn PxSurface shader and how Renderman's nodes work and do. I'm looking for answers to all those questions I posted and if you want me to split them each in each topic, then sure. I thought it's cool to group them all, they all talk about PxRM

Comment: My main question is this. Give me tutorials talking about Renderman 21 inside Blender. Free to paid.

Comment: Best place for tutorials is the link below I provided and here. https://www.youtube.com/user/briansavery

Comment: This site rules clearly state: One question per post. No subjective questions (what is the best/fastest ####); and No asking for tutorials. "*My main question is this. Give me tutorials*" That is not a question and we are not here to serve you, look in the lengthy [resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) post, or do a Google search if it is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is Renderman better than Cycles?`

YES and NO, it handles caustics better, has more options for your lights (light linking), Has had options for years that Cycles is just starting to get. Now the reason I rarely use RM21 is a couple things. 1. Only can use CPU, and they dont have any plans of making it work with GPU (Major Downside). You need another pop up window called "IT" to see your renders. I actually like this because it is so easy to do many render passes with just a click of the button, however it is not the ideal set up to see your quick renders within Blender. Sometimes I just want to switch into render view in Blender to quickly check something. This is not so easy to do with "IT".

`Are renderman's nodes easier and faster than cycles'?`

NO, roughly the same. There are some exceptions though.

I saw this thing about Pixar's new Surface Shader that was used for Finding Dory and other PIXAR movies.

Blender practically has this now  with 2.79 called the Princepled Shader.

`My question is, what is the best way to learn shading and lighting for Renderman INSIDE blender?`

https://renderman.pixar.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?s=&forumid=166

Also, these questions are better to ask here:

https://blenderartists.org/forum/

Comment: Renderman 21 is GPU accelerated! So yeah, it supports GPU just like Cycles does!

Comment: No that is incorrect. The programmer BSAVERY recently mentioned that they wont even open it for GPU because to them its not worth it. They expect you to run it with a renderfarm. Maybe in the future but not with Blender anytime soon.

Comment: Does RenderMan support GPU rendering?
The current version of RenderMan is a multi-threaded software application that generally does not rely on GPU's due to their additional expense and the current fluidity of graphics hardware and supporting software standards. However GPU's are an important aspect of the future direction of rendering that Pixar is currently researching, some of which has already demonstrated in public. For the first time, RenderMan 21 introduces GPU accelerated denoising, and as GPU's mature for comprehensive production usage, we will reveal more in future.

Comment: Rendering on cpus is more power-efficient (when the renderer uses the advantages of cpu complexity - like Corona - light path prediction etc.). Electricity bills are huge concern for render farms. GPUs pack more punch in a smaller form-factor. With Nvidia OptiX and RTX the game is changed and now it's the GPU that's more power efficient.